# Currency symbol for pound converts in html code on ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I have implemented Kendo range slider for price and I am using pound currency. On first load currency loads with its symbol. But on price change I have implemented ajax call and on ajax call currency symbol for pound converts into its html code "£". If I again load the page and it will display symbol again.
Here is my code:

```
  function rangeSliderOnSlide(e) {
                        var rentval = e.values;
                        //update span value when slider change done..
                        $("div#minvalue").text(rentval[0]);
                        $("div#maxvalue").text(rentval[1]);

                        //set the new min and max values below the slider to show current slider points..
                        $("span.currentMinPrice").text('@(Model.SolrPriceRangeFilterContext.CurrencySymbol) ' + rentval[0]);
                        $("span.currentMaxPrice").text('@(Model.SolrPriceRangeFilterContext.CurrencySymbol) ' + rentval[1]);      
                    }

                    function rangeSliderOnChange(e) {
                        var rentval = e.values;
                        var currentURL = $("div#url").text();
                        var url = removeParameter(currentURL, "price");
                        var newUrl = url.replace(/&amp/g, '');
                        url = UpdateQueryString("price", rentval[0] + "-" + rentval[1], newUrl);

                        //update span value when slider change done..
                        localStorage.setItem("selStart", rentval[0]);
                        localStorage.setItem("selEnd", rentval[1]);
                        FiltersPushStateUrl(url); //to update addressbar URL history
                        AjaxCall(url);                            
                    }
```

**//"Model.SolrPriceRangeFilterContext.CurrencySymbol" displays currency symbol.**
Please suggest what should I do to display currency symbol on ajax call? Please note it works fine with "$" symbol.

Thanks.